# Invalid argument to unary operator

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o

Even though there is no line starting with a unary operator, I'm getting the following error in R

```
Error in -h2o.deeplearning(activation = "RectifierWithDropout", hidden = c(200,  : 
invalid argument to unary operator
```

Here is the function call

```
best_model < - h2o.deeplearning( activation = "RectifierWithDropout",
                                            hidden = c(200, 200, 200, 200, 200),
                                            hidden_dropout_ratio = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
                                            loss = "CrossEntropy",
                                            l1 = 1e-5,
                                            epochs = EPOCHS,
                                            distribution = "multinomial",
                                            seed = 5000,
                                            balance_classes = TRUE,
                                            y = c("Churn"),
                                            x = columns,
                                            validation_frame = churn_validation,
                                            training_frame = churn_training

                                            )
```

What could be the issue? I tried shutting down h20 and restarting it is as well but the issue persists. I tried reordering the attributes as well but it still spits out the same error

Comment: Is it a typo `<-`?

Comment: darn, yes :( silly of me